# Removing rows in SQL that have a duplicate column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have looked high and low on SO for an answer over the last couple of hours (subqueries, CTE's, left-joins with derived tables) to this question but none of the solutions are really meeting my criteria..

I have a table with data like this :

```
   COL1  COL2 COL3 
    1     A    0
    2     A    1
    3     A    1
    4     B    0
    5     B    0
    6     B    0
    7     B    0
    8     B    1
```

Where column1 1 is the `primary key` and is an `int`. Column 2 is `nvarchar(max)` and column 3 is an `int`. I have determined that by using this query:

```
select name, COUNT(name) as 'count'
FROM [dbo].[AppConfig]
group by Name
having COUNT(name) > 3
```

I can return the total counts of "A, B and C" only if they have an occurrence of column C more than 3 times.  I am now trying to remove all the rows that occur after the initial value of column 3.  The sample table I provided would look like this now:

```
   COL1  COL2 COL3 
    1     A    0
    2     A    1
    4     B    0
    8     B    1
```

Could anyone assist me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the first row with a ColB-ColC combination, the following will do it:

```
select min(id) as id, colB, colC
from tbl
group by colB, colC
order by id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8ebca/5)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
;WITH numbered_rows as (
SELECT
    Col1,
    Col2,
    Col3,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col2, Col3 ORDER BY Col3) as row
FROM AppConfig)
SELECT 
  Col1,
  Col2,
  Col3
FROM numbered_rows
WHERE row = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(COL1) AS COL1,COL2,COL3 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY  COL2,COL3
ORDER BY COL1
```